# Pyglet unable to play .wav files

Tags: python, playback, pyglet

```
def morse_audio( item ):

    from pyglet import media
    import pyglet
    import time
    import glob
    import os
    import wave
    from contextlib import closing
    files = []
    audios = []
    for file in glob.glob('C:\\Users\\MQ\'s Virual World\\Downloads\\Morse\\*.wav'):
        ass = str(os.path.join('C:\\Users\MQ\'s Virual World\\Downloads\\Morse', file))
        print (ass)
        files.append(ass)
    #audio = media.load(files[1])
    #audio.play()
    #print (len(files))
    one = list(item)
    str_list = [x.strip(' ') for x in one]
    str_list = [x.strip('/') for x in str_list]

    for s in str_list[0]:
        if s != "-" and s !=  ".":
            list(item)
            for letter in item:
               for i in range(0, 51):
                    if letter == " ":
                        time.sleep(1.5)
                        audios.append("noise3.wav")
                        break
                    if letter != letterlst[i] and letter != letterlst[i].lower():
                        continue
                    else:
                        print (files[i])
                        audio = media.load(files[i])
                        audio.play()
                        audios.append(files[i])
                        audios.append("noise2.wav")
                        time.sleep(1)
        else:
            lst = item.split()
            print (' '.join(lst))
            for code in lst:
                for i in range(0, 51):
                    if code == "/":
                        time.sleep(1.5)
                        audios.append("noise3.wav")
                        break
                    if code != morse[i]:
                        continue
                    else:
                        print (files[i])
                        audio = media.load(files[i])
                        audio.play()
                        audios.append(files[i])
                        audios.append("noise2.wav")
                        time.sleep(1)
                        break
    outfile = "sounds.wav"

    data= []
    for file in audios:
        w = wave.open(file, 'rb')
        lol = w.getparams()
        print (lol)
        data.append( [w.getparams(), w.readframes(w.getnframes())] )
        w.close()

    with closing(wave.open(outfile, 'wb')) as output:

    # find sample rate from first file
        with closing(wave.open(audios[0])) as w:
            output.setparams(w.getparams())

    # write each file to output
        for audioo in audios:
            with closing(wave.open(audioo)) as w:
                output.writeframes(w.readframes(w.getnframes()))()))
```

So this code previously worked but I wanted to use different file types other then .wav files but because that worked so poorly I went back to .wav. These are different .wav files but the ones that worked before get the same error message. Which is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MQ's Virual World\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\morsecode.py", line 187, in <module>
    morse_audio("0123456789ÁÄ@&':,$=!-().+?;/_")
  File "C:\Users\MQ's Virual World\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\morsecode.py", line 96, in morse_audio
    audio.play()
  File "C:\Users\MQ's Virual World\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\__init__.py", line 473, in play
    player.play()
  File "C:\Users\MQ's Virual World\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\__init__.py", line 1012, in play
    self._set_playing(True)
  File "C:\Users\MQ's Virual World\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\__init__.py", line 993, in _set_playing
    self._create_audio_player()
  File "C:\Users\MQ's Virual World\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\__init__.py", line 1083, in _create_audio_player
    self._audio_player = audio_driver.create_audio_player(group, self)
  File "C:\Users\MQ's Virual World\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\drivers\directsound\__init__.py", line 502, in create_audio_player
    return DirectSoundAudioPlayer(source_group, player)
  File "C:\Users\MQ's Virual World\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyglet\media\drivers\directsound\__init__.py", line 184, in __init__
    None)
  File "C:\Users\MQ's Virual World\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyglet\com.py", line 125, in <lambda>
    self.method.get_field()(self.i, self.name)(obj, *args)
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 920, in GetResult
OSError: [WinError -2147024809] The parameter is incorrect
```

I've tried .wav files that used to work. It works when I use a .ogg file. Also works with mp3s. Seems only .wav files are giving it issues. Very suddenly and randomly.

Comment: There's a few problems with this question, one being that this works flawlessly on `Python v3.5.1` with `Pyglet 1.2.4`. The second being I'm not sure which `audio.play()` isn't working because you have a lot of them and the lines in your output doesn't corelate to your code (for good and obvious reasons). Could you please post a **minimal example without all the `if letter != ...` stuff?** - And also give us a `.wav` that isn't working? I tried with [Apollo 11 eagle](http://www.wavsource.com/news/news.htm) and that worked.

Comment: Here's the [code](https://gist.github.com/Torxed/1fbc16b3a3aaaad8cc5e3ad8cc0c054d) that I used - Not sure if it will reproduce your issue tho since it's quite minimal.

Comment: @Torxed The issue happens with any .wav file I attempt play. .mp3, .oggs, etc all work fine it is just wavs that produce this error.

Comment: If you get the same error with the code i linked, I'm willing to say that it's not the code that is the problem. It's a OS/driver issue. Could you please update with what OS and version of Python, pyglet and avbin you're running?

Comment: @Torxed That's what I'm assumed, no issue I've resolved it by just making all the wavs into mp3s. The issue occurred after I installed a something I believe. But in case someone stumbles upon this I have windows 7, Python 3.5.2, the latest version of pyglet and avbin version 10 or whatever the last version they had before the project died. Thanks for the help!